# python svg parsing with minidom/etree/lxml

Tags: python, parsing, svg, minidom, xml.etree

With python im trying to parse an svg (xml format) with minidom/etree/lxml
i have following svg file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:shaper="http://www.shapertools.com/namespaces/shaper"
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="5319.4434mm"
   height="6025.5mm"
   viewBox="0 0 5319.4434 6025.5"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg1217"
   inkscape:version="0.92.4 (5da689c313, 2019-01-14)"
   sodipodi:docname="test.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs1211" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.0875"
     inkscape:cx="2965.7333"
     inkscape:cy="12836.281"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer2"
     showgrid="false"
     fit-margin-top="0"
     fit-margin-left="0"
     fit-margin-right="0"
     fit-margin-bottom="0"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="1017"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata1214">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer2"
     inkscape:label="Second_Layer"
     style="display:inline">
    <rect
       style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:10;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1;opacity:1"
       id="rect2567"
       width="1233.7142"
       height="1644.9524"
       x="459.61902"
       y="268.1666" />
  </g>
  <g
     inkscape:label="First_Layer"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(2594.7098,2684.756)"
     style="display:none">
    <g
       transform="matrix(10,0,0,10,-2594.7098,-2684.756)"
       id="Body_Körper116">
      <path
         style="vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke;fill:#000000"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         d="M 241.25,-479.9 V -500 h 17.5 v 20.1 z"
         shaper:cutDepth="0.0001105"
         shaper:pathType="exterior"
         transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,-42.65,18.6)"
         id="path2" />
    </g>
    <g
       transform="matrix(10,0,0,10,-2594.7098,-2684.756)"
       id="Body_Körper114">
      <path
         style="vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke;fill:#000000"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         d="M 141.95,-480.1 V -500 h 16.1 v 19.9 z"
         shaper:cutDepth="0.0001103"
         shaper:pathType="exterior"
         transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,-42.65,18.6)"
         id="path5" />
    </g>
```

which includes 2 layers (layer1 & layer2) with some bodyies in each layer and grouped.
What I want to do is to perform operations (e.g. transform) on those bodies to move them around etc.

I tried minidom and etree, but I can't manage to get a clear picture on how these trees are build and accessible in my case.
Therefore I have a couple of questions and hope someone with more experience can help me to get quickly on the track :)

1. When using either:

   lxml = ET.parse('test.svg')
   svgdoc = lxml.getroot()

or

```
svgdoc = xml.dom.minidom.parse('test.svg')
```

I manage to read the file into the tree. Can somebody tell me how to access each tree, subtree, attribute etc in my case above? Was expecting something like "svgdoc.parent[1].child[1]. attribute to get through the tree and its nodes, but I get a lot of errors.

2. How would I have to access for example the "transform="matrix(10,0,0,10,-2594.7098,-2684.756)" for Body with "id="Body_Körper114" and how the "shaper:cutDepth="0.0001105" nested within the  of Body_Körper114?
3. I can read them by
   `path_d_strings      = [path.getAttribute('d') for path
                   in svgdoc.getElementsByTagName('path')]`
   but if I want to change the transform **not** nested inside path (but directly above ) according to some condition found within  then if I use the getElementsByTagName-Method I end up with e.g. more "transform"-elements as for "shaper:cutDepth" as "transform" occurs not only within path as "shaper:cut..." but also in the body description above , and therefor I can not simply go through the lists by index and apply changes.
4. What I also find strange is that I read the elements from svgdoc into some other lists, make changes in this list, and then write the xml file while the changes are also written.

```html
path = svgdoc.getElementsByTagName("path")
    firstchild = path[0]
    firstchild.attributes["d"].value = "test"
    f = open('test2.svg', 'w')
    f.write(doc.toxml())
    doc.unlink()
```

I would have expected to have to transfer back the lists I have extracted by getElements into svgdoc before saving. How does this structure work?

5. With Inkscape I can remove all the transform parts and put everything to absolute coordinates. As I nee to transform the bodies and move them with my script I would then need to insert a new "node"?!? under path (like "style" or "inkscape") and save this to the xml file. How would I manage this?

Sorry for the long post but this really bugs me and I try to understand whats happening.
I read tutorials, docs, examples but nothing really eplained how to get control over this structure. Furthermore I'm new to python and still have to get to know the syntax (unfortunately without much time as I have 2 small kids)

Thanks for the help, it's really appreciated!
Cheers,

Toby

Answer (score 0):

Your post is too long for me to understand. Here is an example for you. I don't know if it can meet your needs. If you have any questions, please leave a message.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils

html = utils.getFileContent('test.svg')
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
path = doc.getElement('path') # Select element
path.setAttr('d','test') # Edit attribute
while True:
  path = doc.getElement('path',start=path._end)
  if not path: break
  path.setAttr('d','test2')
utils.saveFile('test2.svg', doc.html)
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I appreciate it! unfortunately this doesn't help me as I'm not looking for an alternative to minidom/etree etc, but trying to understand them.
I am already able to read e.g. path and change the attributes.
Whats bugging me is that I don't really understand how the xml tree is stored in those nodes.
for example you have:

layer1 - path - attrib1, attrib2
layer2 - path - attrib1, attrib2

If I now get elements by name "path" i get all elements in layer 1 and 2. but I only want the ones from layer1.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with minidom/etree. You can see its source code.